# Como criar Pojos com as anotations de maneira rápida?

Tags: java, pojo

Tenho um banco de dados com muitas tabelas, tenho que criar o Pojo de cada tabela? Se sim, tem como automatizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projeto Web, brother?
Se estiver usando **JPA** com provedor **Hibernate**, a **IDE Eclipse for Java EE** tem uma funcionalidade para criação de entidades a partir de tabelas, basta selecionar o **projeto** com o botão direito ir em **JPA *tools*** e escolher ***Genereted Entities from tables***. Apartir disto, abrirá uma janela de configuração para o procedimento. Claro, seu projeto terá que estar conectado ao banco de dados em questão, o `persistence.xlm` também deverá estar de acordo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, pelo Eclipse você pode fazer engenharia reversa da sua tabela para uma entidade JPA.

https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm